# Как правильно делать проверку

Tags: javascript

Пишу так

```
 if ( typeof params.id != 'undefined'  ) {
```

Выдаёт всё равно ошибку

> > TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
> >         at null. (services.js:242)
> >         at angular.js:14745
> >         at n.$eval (angular.js:15989)
> >         at n.$digest (angular.js:15800)
> >         at n.$apply (angular.js:16097)
> >         at h (angular.js:10546)
> >         at K (angular.js:10744)
> >         at XMLHttpRequest.z.onload (angular.js:10685)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам же написали "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at null"
params у вас не объект, что вызвало ошибку.

Если вам нужно проверить существует ли id у params и существует ли вообще params, то надо писать так: `if ( typeof params == 'object' && typeof params.id != 'undefined'  ) {`

Comment: точно сам params был undefined, если прописать if(typeof params != 'object')  то ошибка останется, собственно прописал   if(typeof params != 'undefined')

Answer (score 0):

```js
var params = {};
params.id = "Yeah";
if ( params.id !== undefined ){
   alert("Yeah");
}

params.id = undefined;
if ( params.id === undefined ){
   alert("undefined");
}
```

Comment: Всё равно ошибка

Comment: в этом случае надо использовать `!==`, а не `!=`, т.к. знаете ли `null == undefined` вернет `true`

Comment: В вашем случае ошибка тоже останется, ниже в комментарии написал в чём причина, хотя там тоже не совсем правильно написано, в общем тот кто первый исправит на правильную проверку тот  ответ и засчитаю лучшим, спасибо за то что натолкнули на правильный ответ

Comment: @Cladoxylon исправил

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich Работает, проверил

Comment: @Perkovec если params  не существует, то что и было ошибкой, то работать не будет, ниже в ответе почти правильно написано, только ошибка будет если проверять объект ли